# Как добавить иконку в выпадающее меню?

Tags: css, html5, svg

Я пытаюсь  управлять своими `selects` HTML и заменить выпадающий значок SVG, но я не могу его получить.

Вот мой код:

```css
select {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    border-color: blue !important;
    position: relative;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: blue url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='#FFFFFF'/></g></svg>") no-repeat !important;
    background-position-x: 100%;
    background-position-y: 5px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Что я здесь не так делаю?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54207098/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо настроить `viewBox`, так как указанный путь не может быть виден с фактическим `viewBox`.

Затем удалите дополнительное определение высоты, а также удалите `!important`, чтобы иметь возможность установить `background-position`

```css
select {
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    padding-right: 30px !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    border-color: blue !important;
    position: relative;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: blue url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 140 140' width='24' height='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><g><path d='m121.3,34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0l-51,51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8,0-1.6,1.6-1.6,4.2 0,5.8l53.9,53.9c0.8,0.8 1.8,1.2 2.9,1.2 1,0 2.1-0.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2 0.1-5.8z' fill='white'/></g></svg>") no-repeat;
    background-position: right 5px top 50%;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```